# Display images from sqlite3 database to a column in QTableWidget with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

After looking at various examples here and elswhere, I have not been able to show images in 'mydb.db' which is my SQlite3 database to my table QTableWidget in python. Here is my code

```
def fetch_all_learner_data(self):
    connection= sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
    query = "SELECT NAME,ADM,CLASS,STREAM,CATEGORY,GENDER,COUNTY,PARENT,PARENT_CONTACT,PHOTO   FROM learner_data"
    result = connection.execute(query)
    self.classes_table.setRowCount(0)
    for row_number,row_data in enumerate(result):
        self.classes_table.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number,data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.classes_table.setItem(row_number,column_number,QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

This is what  end up getting on the image column in the qtable and which have also really slowed my system.

[image: What displays in the qtable]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build a QIcon based on the data using a QPixmap:

```
def fetch_all_learner_data(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
    query = "SELECT NAME,ADM,CLASS,STREAM,CATEGORY,GENDER,COUNTY,PARENT,PARENT_CONTACT,PHOTO   FROM learner_data"
    result = connection.execute(query)
    self.classes_table.setRowCount(0)
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
        self.classes_table.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            it = QTableWidgetItem()
            if column_number == 9:
                pixmap = QPixmap()
                pixmap.loadFromData(data)
                it.setIcon(QIcon(pixmap))
            else:
                it.setText(str(data))
            self.classes_table.setItem(row_number, column_number, it)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```